# How I can update DNS in /etc/resolve.conf from /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail without rebooting system

Tags: networking, server, updates, network-manager, dns

How I can update DNS in `/etc/resolve.conf` from  `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` without rebooting system

I made below entries in file
`root@server1:/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d`

```
# cat tail
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
```

after this I restarted `resolveconf.service` and `systemd-resolved.service` but still it did not update `/etc/resolv.conf` .
But if i reboot system `/etc/resolv.conf` will be updated with `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` contents.
How I can make `/etc/resolv.conf` update without rebooting system ?

Answer (score 0):

You could investigate other `.service` files to see which one sets up `/etc/resolv.conf`, or just restart all of networking: `service networking restart` (or `service network restart`, I'm not at my 'puter now). If you're accessing remotely, this will disconnect you, and you'll have to reconnect under the new rules, so be sure the changes are correct.

Comment: done root@server1:/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants# systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service
but still file is not updating .
How to check which .service manage /etc/resolve.conf
as per symbolic link it shows this file is linked with resolvconf service, but restartin that also didn't work.
i have restarted named.service also 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Feb 26 18:07 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

Answer (score 0):

Just and update to everyone finally I found service name to update /etc/resolv.conf file .

this service restart update DNS entry in my file .

systemctl restart named-resolvconf.service

And it works :)